# Determine whether content the same across several different variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is a small chunk of the data I am working with:

```
 data<-structure(list(record_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), fracture1_lateral___1 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1_medial___1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1px_lateral___1 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1px_medial___1 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(record_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), fracture1_lateral___1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), fracture1_medial___1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), fracture1px_lateral___1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), fracture1px_medial___1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

And here is a screenshot of the input it originally comes from, each checkbox becomes its own column:
[image]

I want to determine if somebody checked the "same" output on each form.  I.e. if they clicked "Right Condylar" on one form, they also clicked it on the other, like this photo:
[image]

In my data, I know this code could do that for me by creating a new variable that was TRUE/FALSE for whether those two variables said the same thing (which is what I want):

```
data<-data%>%mutate(Same=(fracture1_medial___1==fracture1px_medial___1))
```

My problem is, I need to check that variable in several spots, and there's special rules:
[image]

In that photo, there are 4 places where it says "Right Condylar" and what I need to know is: if either of the boxes on the left were clicked, then was at least one of the boxes on the right clicked?  I.e. if we noticed the scenario in this photo:
[image]

Where "fracture1_lateral_1" and "fracture1px_medial" were both clicked, thats fine and would result in a "TRUE" but this scenario below with "fracture1px_medial" and "fracture1px_lateral" would be FALSE.
[image]

There's probably 10ish "Right Condylar" variables to compare (5ish on each side), but for instance in that photo the "Right Condylar" variables are:

```
data$fracture1_medial_1, data$fracture1_lateral_1, data$fracture1px_medial_1, data$fracture1px_lateral_1
```

Edit per @Ben's comment for clarification:
What I ultimately want would be this column:
[image]

In that photo, you can see that if there's a "1" found in at least one of the left two columns and at least one of the right two, it results in a "Yes", or if its all zero's all the way across its a "Yes", but if there are only "1's" on the left side, or the right side.... its a "No"

Any solutions?  Tidyverse would be preferable simply because I'm used to it.

Comment: Looks like you're working with REDCap checkboxes. Would it be possible to develop a good scaled-down example starting data frame (maybe building off the data included in the post, but that also demonstrates "checking for variable in several spots" and "special rules")? Perhaps come up with a "desired end-result data frame" to demonstrate what you'd like to code to do with the raw data, and what the final result should look like? Then, maybe a generalized answer could be developed.

Comment: @Ben I hope that comment helps clarify, thank you for taking time to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach.

First, would convert data to long format. That will help in looking at similar groups and subgroups, and would be flexible for different needs when analyzing similar data.

Once in long form, you can `group_by` each row or `record_id`, and use appropriate logic. In this case, you are looking at "medial" and "lateral" for both "px" and no "px". The logic is written out, though there may be shortcuts to consider as well using `any` or other ways.

A factor is created to convert the `TRUE` and `FALSE` to "Yes" and "No". The final `right_join` will connect the new column result to your original data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -record_id, 
               names_to = c("number1", "location", "number2"), 
               names_pattern = "^fracture(\\d+)(\\w+)___(\\d+)") %>%
  separate(location, into = c("px", "location"), sep = "_", remove = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  summarise(same = ifelse((value[px == "" & location == "lateral"] | 
                           value[px == "" & location == "medial"]) ==
                          (value[px == "px" & location == "lateral"] |
                           value[px == "px" & location == "medial"]), "Yes", "No")) %>%
  right_join(data)
```

**Output**

```
   record_id same  fracture1_lateral___1 fracture1_medial___1 fracture1px_lateral___1 fracture1px_medial___1
       <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>                <dbl>                   <dbl>                  <dbl>
 1         1 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
 2         2 Yes                       1                    0                       1                      0
 3         3 Yes                       1                    0                       0                      1
 4         4 Yes                       0                    1                       1                      0
 5         5 Yes                       0                    1                       0                      1
 6         6 No                        0                    0                       1                      1
 7         7 No                        1                    1                       0                      0
 8         8 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
 9         9 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
10        10 No                        1                    1                       0                      0
11        11 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
12        12 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
13        13 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
14        14 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
15        15 Yes                       0                    1                       0                      1
16        16 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
17        17 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
18        18 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
19        19 Yes                       0                    0                       0                      0
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(record_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), fracture1_lateral___1 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1_medial___1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1px_lateral___1 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fracture1px_medial___1 = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```